# "Memoirs" in book title - singular or plural verb?

Tags: verb-agreement, titles

I'm editing an article about the Battle of Agincourt. The author quotes his source as follows:

> The *Memoires de Pierre de Fenin* place the battle "between Maisoncelles and Agincourt".

"Memoires" [memoirs] is obviously plural, but the title refers to a single book. So I'm a little confused over the verb agreement.

- Pierre de Fenin's memoirs place...
- The book/source/author places...
- The *Memoires de Pierre de Fenin* place/places...???

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a book title, referring to a single book. The content of the title is irrelevant to the grammar of the sentence. When constructing the sentence, think of the title as simply *Title*:

> ***Title*** **places** the battle "between Maisoncelles and Agincourt".

Or:

> ***Memoires de Pierre de Fenin*** **places** the battle "between Maisoncelles and Agincourt".

---

Note that it's wrong to start your sentence with only the definite article.

You would not say:

> ✘ **The** *Moby Dick* is a tale about a fisherman and a whale.

But you can start the sentence with *the* ***book***:

> **The book** *Moby Dick* is a tale about a fisherman and a whale.

So, if you want to use *the book* in your sentence:

> **The book** *Memoires de Pierre de Fenin* **places** the battle "between Maisoncelles and Agincourt".

---

Of course, if the subject of the sentence weren't the book itself, then the verb could be plural:

> **The memories** recounted in *Memoires de Pierre de Fenin* **place** the battle "between Maisoncelles and Agincourt".

Comment: A good answer indeed.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms what I'd thought, but I hadn't even thought about the use of the definite article being incorrect, too! Many thanks for the detailed response.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally choose the second suggestion, since the first adjusts the title, which I would view as bad practice.

You could also write

> The book "*Memoires de Pierre de Fenin*" places [...]

to be absolutely sure you're right.